# Regular expression to escape inner double quotes in json

Tags: javascript, json, regex, javascript-objects

I have an issue, I was wondering if somebody could help me with a regular expresion to replace this:

```
{"name": "Raul "the cat" Gonzalez"}
```

To this:

```
{"name": "Raul \"the cat\" Gonzalez"}
```

In order to do validations in server side, I need this because I am using a web service to save JSON into the database and I would like to have this flexibility in my web service. I mean I would like to be able to send this:

```
{"name": "Raul "the cat" Gonzalez"}
```

And the logic changes it into:

```
{"name": "Raul \"the cat\" Gonzalez"} //inner quotes escaped
```

Comment: your example isn't even a valid json object

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` will do proper escaping. You shouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: Curious to know why there are double quotes on "the cat", when single quotes would solve it.

Comment: Hi Jason210, the thing is that I need to cover all scenarios because it is possible happen, in fact this happened and I need to write a code as reliable as possible. Thanks for your answer my friend regards

Comment: @RaulGonzalez — Code that tries to recover from any error someone submitting JSON might make when hand-crafting the JSON is going to take a lot of work and be quite likely to break perfectly valid JSON. If someone submits invalid JSON, then give them an error message instead of trying to fix their mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` does exactly what you want:

```js
var object = {'name': 'Raul "the cat" Gonzalez'}; // single quotes, otherwise you would need escaped double quotes already here to avoid a JavaScript error.
console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
```